# In RStudio, how to quickly hide/show a panel?

Tags: rstudio

Is there a keyboard shortcut to quickly hide the left/right panels in RStudio? I can drag the vertical bar to resize the panels but that's cumbersome.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure that there's a hotkey for hiding the left / right / upper / lower panels, but you might find the shortcut keys for zooming to a given quadrant pane useful.

For example, in Linux (and I'm guessing Windows):

```
CTRL+SHIFT+1 = Zoom Source
CTRL+SHIFT+2 = Zoom Console
...
CTRL+SHIFT+0 = Show All Panes
```

The whole list of the pane zoom shortcut keys can be seen under the `View > Panes` menu. These hotkeys seem to be rather recent additions, as the earliest mention that I can see of them is for release [v0.99.902](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/release-notes/).

Answer (score 0):

To hide/show all the right panels you can use CTRl+Shift+1.

(this was tested in Rstudio 2023.06.2)